# jQuery UI CSS Class effects not working in Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, google-chrome

Is it me or do none of the (css) class effects of jQuery UI work in Google Chrome.  I thought it might be my code, but even on the example site they are not working in my chrome.  Other examples work.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/addClass/

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was confirmed as a bug with webkit based browsers

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if you provided a link to the bug.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm doesn't work here either - I am running Chrome 3 beta tho. Are you running the beta as well?

Answer (score 1):

This way worked for me:

```
$('#image-container').attr("style", "width:400px;display:block");
```

Answer (score 0):

I pulled few of my hairs already...before landing on this page. Try wrapping your webkit specific code in `$(window).load()`

```
$(window).load( function() {
    $('#image-container').css('width', 400);

});
```

This worked for me!